Create a Databricks metastore through Terraform
I tried to create a Databricks metastore through Terraform. My service principal (SP) is Owner of the azure subscription that contains the Databricks workspace and also Databricks account admin. Here are the following scripts:
provider.tf:
# Define the provider configuration

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = false
  features {

    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy    = true
      recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults = true
    }
  }

  use_msi = true

}



provider "databricks" {
  # Configuration options
  host                        = module.dbw.databricks_workspace_url
  azure_workspace_resource_id = module.dbw.databricks_id
}


provider "databricks" {
  # Configuration option
  alias      = "accounts"
  host       = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "xxx"
}

modules/databricks_metastore/main.tf:
# Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities

locals {
  workspace_id_map = { for id in var.workspace_ids : id => id }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "st" {
  name                = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "stblob_contributor" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.st.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = var.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "stqueue_contributor" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.st.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Queue Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = var.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "staccount_contributor" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.st.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Account Contributor"
  principal_id         = var.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "eventgd_contributor" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  role_definition_name = "EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor"
  principal_id         = var.object_id
}

resource "databricks_metastore" "dbw_ms" {
  name         = var.metastore_name
  storage_root = "abfss://${var.container_name}@${var.storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "databricks_metastore_assignment" "dbw_ms_assign" {
  for_each     = local.workspace_id_map
  metastore_id = databricks_metastore.dbw_ms.id
  workspace_id = each.value
}

main.dbw.tf:
module "dbw_metastore" {
  depends_on           = [module.dbw]
  source               = "./modules/databricks_metastore"
  object_id            = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.msi["datalake_uc"].principal_id
  storage_account_name = local.datalake.raw.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name  = "my-resource-group"
  metastore_name       = "datalake"
  container_name       = local.datalake.raw.container["landing"].name
  workspace_ids        = [module.dbw.databricks_workspace_id]
}

When I run the Terraform plan, I get the following output:
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.dbw_metastore.databricks_metastore.dbw_ms is tainted, so must be replaced

I run then the Terraform Apply:
╷
│ Error: cannot create metastore: UpdateMetastore Nothing to update.
│ 
│   with module.dbw_metastore.databricks_metastore.dbw_ms,
│   on modules/databricks_metastore/main.tf line 40, in resource "databricks_metastore" "dbw_ms":
│   40: resource "databricks_metastore" "dbw_ms" {

My metastore is created even if this error is present. Where does the error come from? I need to solve this error because this latter prevents me to do subsequent actions related to the metastore (like metastore assignment on a workspace,...). Each Terraform steps are run in Azure DevOps through a CI/CD pipeline. How can I solve this issue?

See https://serverfault.com/a/1012499, https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-taint and https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/taint

Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to use Terraform  taint. It appears when I created the resource

the articles basically explain what that error means and how to eventually fix it.

I went through the papers. Indeed, it meant it has been badly created. The first time run the Terraform plan, there were no "tainted" message. The Terraform apply still gives "Error: cannot create metastore: UpdateMetastore Nothing to update.". I don't want to do a "terraform untaint" if it has already been badly created since beginning.

It's up to you to decide what to do. Maybe go to the portal and double-check if the resource is healthy or not. If it's healthy and you don't want to recreate it use the untaint command; otherwise let Terraform recreate it? See also: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/bucket-tainted-so-must-be-replaced/49604/2

If I recreate the resource, terraform apply always gives the error: "Error: cannot create metastore: UpdateMetastore Nothing to update." I wonder if it's not related to how I configure the Databricks provider

Try removing the resource from the state file and removing it from the Azure Portal, and then apply changes again

If you deploy your terraform template locally without using pipelines, will the deployment work? It may help isolate the issue caused by the template definition or deployment workflow & environment.

Unfortunately, I can't deploy my terraform template locally. I don't have access. I can only deploy through Azure DevOps

@Quynh-MaiChu, Your pipeline can be configured to authenticate against client-Id and client-secret to authenticate access to Azure, you can also setup the same environment variables locally for authentication. In all cases, did you check whether the error was caused by the terraform template or the pipeline agent environment?

See more details to Authenticate Terraform to Azure

I am using service connection on Azure DevOps and this latter is the service principal that is used by Terraform for Azure resource deployment. The SP is owner of the subscription. It's strange because it works for deploying workspace and cluster. I don't know why it gives trouble for metastore.

I know your pipeline was referencing the underlying service principal of your ARM service connection to deploy resources defined in terraform template into Azure. You can follow the document that I just shared to setup local authentication against the same service principle and test the terraform deployment from local environment first then move on to use pipelines. If you the issue was caused by the tf template rather than pipeline agent environment, why bother reaching out to the subcommunity of Azure DevOps?

Your terraform init command should probably be using the remote backend to store your tfstate file right? What was the value of the block resource "databricks_metastore" "dbw_ms" like in that tfstate file? Was it correct?

"module": "module.dbw_metastore",
"mode": "managed",
"type": "databricks_metastore",
"name": "dbw_ms",
"provider": "provider["registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks"]",
"instances": [
{
"status": "tainted",
....
}

I am not so familiar with the databricks terraform resources as devops workflow. Hopefully some experts on databricks may help figure out the why the deployed resource was in tainted status. If possible, please share a minimal reproducible sample template with detailed steps to help understand how the issue was reproduced.

Hi @Quynh-MaiChu, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Vinary below to use terraform refresh to correct the format of the tfstate file? Hope the solution helps. Thx.

I had this issue, just turned out to be the account provider being explicitly required on the metastore module. The error handling response in the provider doesn't seem to surface this information very well.
i.e
provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "azure_account"
  host       = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id =  var.databricks_account_id
}


resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
  name = "metastore"
  // Provider Defined here
  provider = databricks.azure_account
  region = var.location
  storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    var.storage_account_name,
    var.unity_container_name
  )
  force_destroy = true
}

